# Merge Ribbon Groups in DevExpress Ribbon Control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, ribbon

I am using C#, VS 2010 and DevExpress v10. I am making Ribbon Form in which i want to merge two ribbon page groups.
My code is as follows:

```
RibbonControl RibbonControl = new RibbonControl();
RibbonPage page1 = new RibbonPage("Home");
RibbonPageGroup group1 = new RibbonPageGroup("File");
RibbonPageGroup group2 = new RibbonPageGroup("new");
this.Controls.Add(RibbonControl);

BarButtonItem itempanel = RibbonControl.Items.CreateButton("Open...");
group1.ItemLinks.AddRange(new BarItem[] { itempanel });
page1.Groups.Add(group1);
page1.Groups.Add(group2);
RibbonControl.Pages.Add(page1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me what the exactly you want to merge, because the [Ribbon merging](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3451) can't be performed on ribbon page groups rather than different ribbon controls itself.

If you are talking about building ribbon page group layout I  suggest you review the following "How-to" article: [How to: Create a RibbonControl in Code](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2513)

If you are talking about the ribbons merging, please take a look at [How to: Merge Ribbon Controls](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument7349) article.

In another cases please contact the [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) directly.